# Serialisation not working when inheriting from monobehaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to do a property drawer for a class that i need to be updated as well as editable from the editor. 
If i make the class a monobehaviour the serialisation stops working, but if i remove the monobehaviour inheritance it wont update with the game loop.

Is there any way to have both? I would need the object to be able to instantiate with default (empty) values if a monobehaviour script has  non instantiated reference.

```
[Serializable]
public class MySmallTestProp : MonoBehaviour, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private string name;
    
    [SerializeField] 
    private string _name;
    
    [SerializeField] 
    private float _someFloat;
    
    public float someFloat;

    public MySmallTestProp()
    { }

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        name = _name;
    }
}


    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(MySmallTestProp))]
public class MySmallTestPropPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    float rowHeight;
    int rowSpacing = 5;
    int index;
    Rect currentPosition;
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty prop, GUIContent label)
    {
        rowHeight = base.GetPropertyHeight(prop, label);
        var rows = 2;
        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            rows++;
        }
        else
        {
            rows++;
        }

        return rowHeight * rows;
    }
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        index = 1;
        currentPosition = position;
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);


        var nameProp = property.FindPropertyRelative("_name"); 
        
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(NextPosition(), nameProp, new GUIContent("Name"));
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    Rect NextPosition()
    {
        currentPosition.height = rowHeight;
        currentPosition.y = rowSpacing + (rowHeight + rowSpacing) * index++;
        return currentPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do a PropertyDrawer, you should inherit from PropertyDrawer or PropertyAttribute. Also check this thread on unity forum, maybe helps: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-a-propertydrawer-receive-onafterdeserialize-and-onbeforeserialize-events.859420/

Comment: Sorry my bad. Thats the class not the drawer. The drawer inherits from property drawer for sure. It works as long as the drawed class is not a monobehaviour.

Comment: Ive added the property drawer as well

Comment: And do you have a class inheriting from PropertyAttribute?

Comment: No? Why should i?

Comment: I've added an answer to respond your "Why?" comment, if I'm wrong and my answer is is not related with the objective of your question, please tell me and I'll remove the answer ^^

Comment: Why does your class inherit from `MonoBehaviour` in the first place? you are not "allowed" to have a constructor for a `MonoBehaviour` nor create instances using `new` anyway. A `MonoBehaviour` is a `UnityEngine.Object` which already has its own property drawer .. an object reference field.

Comment: If this is actually supposed to be a `MonoBehaviour` so attached to a certain `GameObject` .. then I don't understand what the custom Inspector and custom Serialization is good for at all ... What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @derHugo Aw shoot. I can see now i just made myself confused trying different things. The last thing i tried was using a MB instead but of course thats not right. Ok so what i need is a class that is used as properties in Monobeaviours, that can be serialised and edited in the view and that updates. I started out using a non MB custom class with a property drawer and then a static class that made sure they updated. I dont want the parent MB class to have to call an update method on this property, id like it to work by itself.

Comment: And it did kind of work but the static class lost the reference to the properties since it cant be serialised. So what i want is to create a property like class, that can be edited and that updates like an MB. Maybe its not possible?

Comment: Updated when and how? And still, what is the custom drawer good for/supposed to do/solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly what you want to achieve is having a class which is

- Serializable
- has some default field values
- Receives an Update call every frame

Actually I don't think you need any custom property drawer for this.

First two points are as simple as having e.g.

```c#
[Serializable]
public class Example
{
    // By default this has the value "Default String"
    public string someString = "Default String";

    // This can be edited only via the Inspector
    // by default it is 42
    [SerializeField] private float someFloat = 42.0f;

    // This is a read-only public access
    public float SomeFloat => someFloat;
}
```

Now to the last and tricky part - the update calls.

The easiest way is to have a dedicated `MonoBehaviour` like e.g.

```c#
public class UpdateDispatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Storing the instance for Singleton Pattern
    private static UpdateDispatcher _instance;

    // Register to this event to receive one call each Update
    public static event Action OnUpdate;

    // This method is automatically called by Unity when the application is started
    // or you enter play mode in the editor
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Init()
    {
        // _instsnce is already assigned and alive?
        if(_instance) return;

        // Otherwise search for one in the scene
        _instance = FindObjectOfType<UpdateDispatcher>();

        // Found one?
        if(_instance) return;

        // Otherwise create it now
        _instance = new GameObject(nameof(UpdateDispatcher)).AddComponent<UpdateDispatcher>();
    }

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // Does another instance already exist?
        if(_instance && _instance != this)
        {
            // Destroy this one
            Destroy (gameObject);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise assign this as the instance and make sure it isn't destroyed when the scene chsnges
        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        // Call the event every frame if something is registered
        OnUpdate?.Invoke ();
    }
}
```

And then you can use [`ISerislizationCallbackReceiver`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) but not for actually doing the serialization (it is already done automatically for the fields) but rather for registration to the update callback like e.g.

```c#
[Serializable]
public class Example, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    // By default this has the value "Default String"
    public string someString = "Default String";

    // This can be edited only vis the Inspector
    // by default it is 42
    [SerializeField] private float someFloat = 42.0f;

    // This is a read-only public access
    public float SomeFloat => someFloat;

    // Nothing to do here, only needed for the interface
    public void OnBeforeSerialize() { }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        // Register to the Update event
        // It is save to unregister before registering even if we haven't been registered before
        // this makes sure we are registered only exactly once
        UpdateDispatcher.OnUpdate -= Update;
        UpdateDispatcher.OnUpdate += Update;

    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        someFloat += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer should be more like a comment, but due to the extension I've decided to post it here.*

The objective of a PropertyDrawer is to display properties differently on the editor.
To achieve that you need 2 things:

1.One class that inherits from PropertyAttribute, this will be the reference used in your future scripts.

2.Another class that inherits from PropertyDrawer, here you can type HOW to display the attribute.

One implementation example of a property drawer that shows an attribute without leting the user to edit it from editor:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class DisplayWithoutEdit : PropertyAttribute
{

}

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(DisplayWithoutEdit))]
public class DisplayWithoutEditDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        return EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(property, label, true);
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        GUI.enabled = false;
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label, true);
        GUI.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it on another script doing something like:

```
[DisplayWithoutEdit] public float randomNumber = 0f;
```

Comment: "To achieve that you need 2 things:" i think you are completely wrong. If im not mistaken a property drawer and a property attribute are to different things. Yes they can be used in combination but its not required. And i cant see how that would solve my problem.

Comment: Oh crap, now I see your problem. You're right, PropertyAttribute is not required, it can just be a Serializable class, but a Monobehaviour script marked as Serializable should control the way they serialize by you if I'm not wrong (again). If this is your problem, you should take a look on how to specify your serialization/deserialization: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization-Custom.html